# how to create dataframe in a specified manner in r?

Tags: r, dplyr

i have two dataframe

```
fg=data.frame(fullna=c("abd compa","bcd comp","xy compa"),
          shortf=c("abc","bcd","xy"))

dat=data.frame(Pri_d=c('2020-01-17','2020-01-24','2020-01-31'))
```

I want to create a dataframe d3 whose 1st column will date of 1st dataframe and and rest of the columns would be of names(fg$shortf ) of NA values

**Required dataframe**

```
df=data.frame(Pri_d=c('2020-01-17','2020-01-24','2020-01-31'),
              abc = NA,
              bcd= NA,
              xy = NA)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign `dat` to `df` and create new columns in `df` from `fg$shortf`.

```
df <- dat
df[fg$shortf] <- NA
df

#       Pri_d abc bcd xy
#1 2020-01-17  NA  NA NA
#2 2020-01-24  NA  NA NA
#3 2020-01-31  NA  NA NA
```